# ui.bootstrap.modal doesn't seem to be modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm looking at the online demo of the modal popup here...

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

It appears that clicking anywhere on the screen closes the modal popup.  Isn't this the opposite of modal?

Comment: I'm an idiot.  Use backdrop: 'static'

Answer (score 0):

Use backdrop: 'static'

Simple really.